# Class cannot subclass 'QObject' (has type 'Any') using mypy

Tags: python, pyqt, subclassing, type-hinting, mypy

I have a class that subclasses QObject. Everyting works fine but when I run mypy on it I get the error:

```
"error: Class cannot subclass 'QObject' (has type 'Any')"
```

At the moment I am totally stuck. I Have been reading the mypy docs but couldn't find where the error was.

Here the code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject

class ServiceLocator(QObject):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        ...
```

Cheers.

Comment: Never used mypy. But the -> looks wonky. An initializer doesn’t return anything.

Comment: Sorry but, You are wrong.  __ init __ is required to return None. In fact it does, but implicitly in this case.

Comment: Just saw that - yep. As I said, not a user. Good luck :)

Comment: Have a look at this issue that appears to be the same as yours: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4180 and is related to accessing modules in other files. Guido says, "You need to tell mypy to check both files."

Comment: This helped me. Did not solved my problem but made me achieve a "solution"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This error occurs when mypy doesn't have type information for a class (in your case due to a lack of stubs) and you have `--disallow-subclassing-any` turned on. You can either disable this flag, add typing information, or, as you pointed out, put a `# type: ignore` to silence the error.

Comment: I recommend to use more specific error type (`# type: ignore[MYPY_ERR_TYPE]`, [MYPY_ERR_TYPE] would be [misc] in this case) to prevent possible ignoring of all other mypy errors.

Answer (score 8):

In order to leave a record on how I get around this I will answer my own question.

As the previous comment suggests, the error arise because `mypy` doesn't have information about `QObject`. I tried to add the `.pyi` files to `mypy` in the third-party folder from [here](https://github.com/Ultimaker/Uranium/tree/master/stubs/PyQt5) or you can try building from sources `PyQt5`.

Everything worked but a lot of other errors arose so I finally decided to use:

```
#type: ignore
```

on this lines and get rid of the error until type hinting is better supported for this lib.

Cheers.

Comment: "until type hinting is better supported for this lib" - 
if you did own the lib, how would you have fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening to me in a library that was fully typed. The problem was that these objects were not defined as public in the `__all__` variable inside of the library ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html?highlight=__all__#importing-from-a-package))