# How to annotate my subclass to avoid mypy error: Class cannot sublass "Foo" (has type "Any")

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have a common library, `lib_common` that defines a basic pydantic `BaseModel` that I use in all other  packages:

```
├── lib_common
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
```

where `models.py` contains:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Extra

class StrictBaseModel(BaseModel):
   class Config:
        extra = Extra.forbid
```

Whenever I try to import this into other packages and inherit from `StrictBaseModel` to define a pydantic model, I get the
`error: Class cannot subclass "StrictBaseModel" (has type "Any")`

```py
from pydantic import Field

from lib_common.models import StrictBaseModel

class Foo(StrictBaseModel):
    bar: str = Field(...)
```

I haven't found a good answer to *what* that actually means. What hints to I need to add to not get this warning? I don't want to just mute it with a `# type: ignore` or change my mypy settings.
It's really weird to me that this error only occurs since `lib_common` is a separate python package that my other packages depend on.

I've seen multiple posts on this, with good answers like here: [mypy calls error: Class cannot subclass 'ObjectType' (has type 'Any') on graphene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52227841/mypy-calls-error-class-cannot-subclass-objecttype-has-type-any-on-graphen) that says to build a stub-file for the package you are importing. But these are all exclusively using external libraries. However, I have the option to just type-hint my imported/inherited class correctly.

How do I solve this? Thanks

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I am surprised that other people haven't hit this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If `lib_common` is a separate *package*, then there is nothing weird here.

[PEP561](https://peps.python.org/pep-0561/) explains it quite well: if your package contains inline annotations (e.g. you consider it typed and do not ship separate stub files), then it needs a `py.typed` marker in root.

There is an example of such package in [mypy documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installed_packages.html#creating-pep-561-compatible-packages). Quote:

> If you would like to publish a library package to a package repository yourself (e.g. on PyPI) for either internal or external use in type checking, packages that supply type information via type comments or annotations in the code should put a py.typed file in their package directory. For example, here is a typical directory structure:

```
setup.py
package_a/
    __init__.py
    lib.py
    py.typed
```

`py.typed` marker is just an empty file named `py.typed` and located in appropriate place.